# how to save cluster seeds for a further scoring purpose

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm building a k-means clustering model in Python. However, I'm not sure how to save the cluster centroids and how to use them for a future scoring purpose.
I always want to assign the same cluster IDs when I use the model later.
I'd appreciate if someone has a clear code to show how to do this.

Update :

Hi @HannounYassir , sure , sorry I should have done this previously :

Imagine my dataset name is data_clean and all the variables are standardized and cleaned before hand.

```
# define the cluster variables

cluster_vars=data_clean[['A' , 'B' , 'C']]

# Interpret 4 cluster solution for the data

model_4=KMeans(n_clusters=4,  random_state=30)
model_4.fit(cluster_vars_copy)
clusassign=model_4.predict(cluster_vars_copy)

# Score the customers from last year by using the model created. Imagine my new dataset is clustervars_new

model_4.fit_predict(clustervars_new)
clusassign_new=model_4.fit_predict(clustervars_new)
```

I'm 100% sure that I am missing something in the scoring phase as I haven't saved the centroid seeds. So, it might use the same model however, I am concerned that the cluster IDs being assigned will be totally random than the original dataset

Comment: Can you post any attempt you have made?

Comment: Hi @HannounYassir , I've edited my original post with my attempt

Comment: Why are you concerned? Why do you use `fit_predict` instead of `predict`?

Comment: Hi @Anony-Mousse , good question :) I have replicated a code and it was using that, I'd be glad if you tell the main difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `fit_predict`.

It first learns a *new* clustering, then "predicts".

But you want to `predict` using the old clustering.

I believe reusing the classification API of `fit`/`predict`/`fit_predict` was a rather poor design decision in sklearn. For classification this is convenient, but clustering is not classification and most clustering algorithms can not "predict" on new data at all.